# Verify that Java classes implement toString()

Tags: java, static-analysis, findbugs, checkstyle, pmd

As a part of the regular static analysis of my program, I would like to check that classes are likely to have sane `toString()` methods. Probably not that every class implements them, but perhaps that no instantiable concrete class uses `Object`'s implementation of `toString()`.

Is there a lint toolkit that checks for this? The ones I currently use are FindBugs and CheckStyle; I haven't found an obvious way to check using either of those. I'm also looking at adding PMD to my lint suite, and would be open to something in Sonar as well. So I would prefer to do it using a tool already in my tool chest, but if I need to add yet another tool I will consider it.

Comment: I would use CheckStyle and create a custom rule. Sounds like a good rule - you should contribute it to the open source code base.

Comment: Ah, more rules! It's like a strip club.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using the Checkstyle *[Regexp](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_misc.html#Regexp)* check:

```xml
<module name="Regexp">
    <property name="format" value="public\s+String\s+toString\s*()"/>
    <property name="message" value="All classes must implement toString()"/>
    <property name="ignoreComments" value="true"/>
</module>
```

This even recognizes commented-out `toString()` methods as not present. I tried it using Checkstyle 5.6 and eclipse-cs, but it should also work with earlier versions.

Comment: This is pretty close, thanks. It doesn't cover the case where a class inherits a perfectly serviceable `toString()` (e.g. from `AbstractList`), but it may well be what I need.